# Help in increasing swap file size

Tags: 20.04, ram, storage

I have an existing virtual storage but it is not enough and I cannot find a solution to this problem. I want to increase my existing virtual memory size. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the virtual memory? on the hard drive or in a file?

Comment: How large is the current size?

Comment: Idk current size is 2gb. And my ram is 4gb. Ubuntu runs out of ram quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Increase `swapfile` size to match RAM size

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: use instructions here to make the swap file permanent: https://www.javacodemonk.com/permanent-swap-space-in-centos-and-ubuntu-f36bb1bf

Missing commands: 


$ sudo nano /etc/fstab 


add this line to the fstab file and save:    /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0