# Host and fstab file messed up after try to change swap size

Tags: mount, fstab, swap, read-only, hosts

I was trying to increase the swap size of my Ubuntu. I, naïve, followed the steps of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331718/1765376):

> Check the swap that is in use:
>
> ```
> sudo swapon -s
>
> If swap partition(s) are found:
>
> sudo swapoff -a
> sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
>
> Add # before the UUID of the swap partition(s):
>
> # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
>
> Add a line for the swapfile, if one does not exist:
>
> swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
>
> Create the swapfile:
>
> sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
>
> where X is swapfile's size in GB:
>
> sudo mkswap /swapfile
> sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
> sudo swapon /swapfile
>
> Reboot:
>
> sudo reboot
> ```

After that, my computer only starts in recovery mode.

I tried to follow [this anwser](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277621). But the error `unable to resolve host my-laptop-name: Temporary failure in name resolution` appears and make the process to fail.

I tried to fix it following [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1343976) that says that the name of the host in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts must be the same. It was wrong in /etc/hosts. But the file is read-only and I can't write on it, even with sudo.

I checked /etc/fstab and notice that I, dumb, put # to the UUID to the the boot disk, not only to the swap thing. I tried to erase the #. But that file is read-only too. I want to kill myself right now :).

If it's not clear after all this, I don't know much about Linux.

Edit 1:

My version of Ubuntu is Desktop 22.04.3 LTS

When I do sudo `sudo nano /etc/fstab` to erase # from boot line, `[ File '/etc/fstab' is unwritable`. The same happens with /etc/hosts.

Edit 2:

I edited the boot option in the GRUB and it worked to edit both /etc/fstab and /hosts.

Now I am struggling because when I try to boot normally the system raises an error about swap. This the error:

```
[0.219748] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.DGPV],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330)
[0.219765 ACPI Error: Aborting method \SB.PC00.PEG0.PCRP._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-596)

/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 848739/15597568 files, 29875721/62383360 blocks

[2.251365] systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.

[3.057060] iwlwifi <ipv6> BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

I tried to recreate swap file like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277621/1765376). These are the commands I run to do so:

```
swapoff -a
rm /swapfile 
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096
chmod 600 /swapfile

mkswap /swapfile
#anwer to this line is:
# setting up swapspace version 1, size 4 GiB
# no label, UUID=<long UUID>

swapon /swapfile
```

Then I review /etc/fstab. At the end there's the line `/swapfile    none    swap  sw   0  0`. There's the line with UUID with the boot partion too. But there's no line with the UUID that `mkswap /swapfile` returned. And the error when trying to boot still happens.

Comment: The file `/etc/fstab` or the file-system table for your system required *elevated* privileges to edit, ie. did you include a `sudo` command at the start of your edit command?  (ie. to elevate your privileges so you had access to WRITE to the file??)

Comment: Thanks. I just edited the question. Let me know if more details will be helpful.

Comment: If the file-system itself is *read-only*, that is mostly likely because of either it was mounted that way; or more likely if it was mounted RW (*read-write*) it'll only switch to RO (*read-only*) on detection of error(s) with problems appearing in system logs as to why. Best action in that case varies on why (ie. reading logs (`dmesg`, `journactl` etc) to see why); then it maybe reboot using *live* and perform file-system checks OR checking drive health or for hardware issues.. You've added 22.04 or the release; not which product (Server? Desktop? etc) as they have different defaults

Comment: Please provide the relevant logs (`journalctl`, `dmesg`) at the time when you failed to activate the swapfile. You can also run `blkid /swapfile` to check the file itself.

Comment: Oh, and I've seen you asked a new question on this. Maybe just reverse the second edit so that the answers here can help others.

Comment: @mcendu yees, I make the other question. Let's follow the topic there. I will resolve this question for you helped me to make /etc/hosts and /etc/fstab editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Linux command line mounts root as read-only on boot (more precisely, just after initramfs).

The safest way is to do the following:

- Reboot to GRUB; if you are greeted with a blank screen, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- Select Ubuntu's boot entry. Don't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>; instead, edit the boot entry. The bottom of the GRUB menu tells you what you can do.
- There is a line starting with `linux`. Remove all `ro` parameters from that line. Go to the end of that line and add the parameter `rw`.
- Boot. Refer to the bottom of the screen for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to modify/etc/fstab and /etc/hosts with `sudo nano`. But the alert `[ File '/etc/fstab' is unwritable]` appears and the changes can't be saved because of the error `Read-only file system`.

Comment: @Simón In this case the filesystem is mounted `ro`. I've attempted a new solution for this.

Comment: let me know if I am understanding well. In that boot option edit interface, the line that start with linux is this one: `linux     /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic root=UUID=<long UUID> ro quiet splash $vt-handoff`. When you say "remove all ro parameters" you mean to delete all that follows "ro" in that line, and "ro" itself?

Comment: Delete just `ro` itself; replace that with `rw`.

Comment: it workeeed. I could edit both /etc/hosts and /etc/fstab, big win. Now I'm struggling with the swap. I wrote the details in the edit 2 of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this! When I was starting with Ubuntu I broke my systems with fstab so many times I wrote down a procedure for how to fix them. Here ya go:

1. Boot the computer to an Ubuntu live USB and select "try Ubuntu"
2. Open a terminal and issue a `sudo blkid` , this will list the drives and partitions with UUIDs and labels. Identify the system partition.
3. In the terminal issue a `sudo mount /dev/sd__ /mnt` where sd__ is
   the system partition you determined in step 2, probably sda1. **Notice the space before /mnt**
4. Edit fstab and fix the problem with a `sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab` Be sure to save your work.
5. Reboot into your fixed system! Remember to remove the live USB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't have a Live USB nor another computer to make it. So I preferred the other solution.